# Is it considered plagiarism for a professor to use uncited sources in teaching materials?

Tags: teaching, professorship, plagiarism

I have a professor at my university who uses content from an un-cited textbook that he has never referenced anywhere, including his green sheet (syllabus), as an additional resource. At least some slides he has used include parts of content that have been re-worded and others that are 100% the same. I noticed this by Googling for textbooks on the material we're studying in class and found that examples given in one that I found were exactly the same as what he has provided.

Would this technically be plagiarism? Should he be given the benefit of the doubt in this situation?

Comment: Are you talking about his teaching materials or papers he published?

Comment: @scaaahu these would be teaching materials. Can't comment on anything he's published.

Comment: Somewhat related: http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/1744/64

Comment: When I was in grad school, Professor X took many of his homework questions and exam questions from a similar textbook, which turned out to be the one I had for the undergraduate version of the same class. U-grad grade, B-minus. Grad grade, A. Needless to say, he didn't credit the second book, but I recognized the problems.

Comment: Regardless of whether it amounts to plagiarism, this paints a picture to me of someone who is not doing a conscientious job teaching the course.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus, well, announcing "this exam/homework question comes from book X" will send everybody to look it up instead of solving the problem... Sure, taking *all* (or most) questions from the same book is sheer lazyness.

Comment: At the very least it's bade style to reproduce sources to a large extent without any citation in teaching materials, I would say. I mean that it looks a bit dishonest and not completely open as well as might actually be interesting to the reader to know.

Comment: If you're a student I'd focus on hunkering down instead, you're letting yourself be distracted. If you're another instructor, why bother?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Plagiarism involves dishonesty: taking someone else's work and leading others to believe it is your own.

In the case of unpublished teaching materials, I don't think it's assumed that all the examples, etc., a professor uses are original unless an outside source is cited. So I wouldn't strictly consider this plagiarism (though citing outside sources is definitely preferable to not citing them).

It's possible that in your academic culture it *is* assumed that all of a professor's materials are original, in which case, the above would not apply.

Comment: That's definitely possible and would make sense. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Teaching has some resistance to being called plagiarism. For instance, you cannot criticize a  professor for not mentioning Newton while he talks about gravity.

Comment: @RenaeLider I'd certainly criticize a professor for not mentioning Newton while talking about gravity! But my criticism wouldn't be that they were plagiarizing. :-)

Comment: @ff524, could you elaborate on what you mean by "academic culture"? When you say that, would you be referring to university policies or just a general opinion of how the system is run (in regards to integrity and such)?

Comment: @Null See [this answer](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/a/1212/11365). It has nothing to do with integrity; it's about what the default assumption is with respect to teaching materials. *I* don't know of any place where professors are assumed by default to have created all their materials unless otherwise stated, but I can't rule out the possibility that there may be such a place.

Comment: It should be added that in many countries, (re)using textbook (or any) material for teaching purposes is perfectly legal (with some caveats).

Comment: I don't see why we need an insight into the person's state of mind when we diagnose plagiarism (it's different regarding whether we want to excuse it etc): instead of requiring a sense of whether this was done dishonestly or not I would say that we simply ask whether this was a case of using the work of someone else as if it's the professor's own, without appropriate citation? On the face of it it looks like the answer to the question is 'yes'.

Comment: @ctokelly My point is that the professor is *not* "using the work of someone else as if it's the professor's own" because there is no implication here that it's the professor's own material. (Hence no "as if it's the professor's own.")

Comment: This answer, while probably accurate with regard to the academic customs, neglects that plagiarism often happens without intent to be dishonest, but simply out of ignorance of the law and the meaning of plagiarism. For example, many students copy-paste wikipedia into their homework introduction, and in good faith think there is nothing wrong with it. The case described in the question feels both similar to that, and indeed very common in Academia.

Comment: @BenoîtKloeckner: But one crucial difference is that students agree to homework/thesis policies (e.g. sign that all 3rd party sources are cited) whereas teachers typically do not sign a similar declaration. And e.g. the German version of the copyright legislation does have a "fair use" of copying small parts of a work for teaching (§ 52a) which does not appear in the list of fair uses for which the source must be given (§ 63). According to this, showing a few examples from a book to the students of the course is OK (btw. authors/publishers receive compensation via VGWort).

Answer (score 8):

Note that I'm not in the US, but in my experience generally it's never implied that all the teaching material is original. There often is a hereditary element too, or the department has common material they share.

Also consider that the only sensitive material in most courses could be copyrighted images. There's no copyright on Newton's law. Plagiarism would be saying that you discovered Newton's law, not copying another teachers' material.

I've noticed that some people put a password on all their PDFs and say it's because of the material they put in it which they don't want to show up in google images. 
Often, I've noticed that it's a mix of stuff they wrote with images from those PPTs you can get from the textbook minisites, given free of charge by the publishers so that teachers can use the same pictures that are also in the books. 
I haven't read the terms and conditions the publishers put on those slide shows but maybe they don't want the images to be republished without a full citation of the source, hence the practice to keep access restricted to the participants.

Answer (score 5):

The simple answer is no.

Usually, courses are being taught with the same material every semester which is "inherited" from one lecturer to the next one and usually begins with some textbook so that's not unusual - no one assumes that it is an original material.

More than that, if a lecturer is using exercises from some textbook in class he might also use them for homework sheets and then he would prefer not to disclose their origin in case there are also answers in the textbook.

Comment: This one is tricky - attribution vs keeping answers away . Would it be nice to add citations and links to the original source once the assignment has been turned in maybe?

Answer (score 4):

Teaching is tricky:

- My university has a one-year post-doc that has a one-course teaching obligation. One of the applicants submitted the required syllabus for the course -- but except for the title, it was a 100% copy/paste of another person's syllabus (including the course description and assignments)  without attribution. This *might* have been forgivable if the source was the applicant's mentor, but it wasn't. Needless to say, we didn't give the person the post-doc although this wasn't the primary reason.
- That all being said -- when planning classes, I think it's common to look for syllabuses to draw on. That's why many professional societies have syllabus databases. You should attempt to make the course your own, but if someone has a great cluster of readings for teaching Dunning-Kruger, I think it's well within fair use to use those sections.
- When teaching 100 level classes, I think it's fairly common for professors to look at intro textbooks other than the course textbook. Often these texts have course plans, etc. I don't think it's uncommon for faculty to integrate these into their lectures, but I do think if you're copy/pasting that you should at least attribute.

Comment: You have applicants for temporary faculty positions submit syllabi for the course they would teach if they were hired?  Wow.

Comment: Yes. It's a one year post-doc with a one-course teaching obligation -- usually in the person's area of specialty. Most view it as a positive -- they get to have Famous University® listed in their teaching portfolio.

Comment: I'm impressed.  (Not to make a big deal about it, but...I do know **y**our university.  Even so I learned something from this answer.)

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: Not that this is necessarily the case in RoboKaren's situation, but my understanding is that this is much more common in the humanities than in e.g. math. (In the humanities the creation of the syllabus is a much larger project, and much more personal, so copying someone else's would *certainly* ensure you wouldn't get the job.)

Comment: For me, the issue is more intellectual laziness than plagiarism. Each of the readings in my (humanistic) social sciences course is designed to work with the other readings and lectures in a particular synergistic way. I post my syllabi online but would find it strange if someone copied them wholesale -- I would wonder if they would be able to teach the class adequately given that they don't know the motivations behind the readings, or what the lecture/discussion plan is for that day.

Comment: I routinely give faculty taking over "my" courses my syllabus material, assignment problems, lecture slides, exam material, etc. and tell them no citation is necessary.  (I've tried to be very careful to credit the work of others, so a problem from a textbook would include a citation.)  If it matters, I teach information technology, computer science, and *uh* ethics.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand the word, **what you describe is factually [plagiarism](http://www.plagiarism.org/plagiarism-101/what-is-plagiarism/)**, which includes both (1) passing others words and ideas as one's own, and (2) using another's production without giving credit. In most classes, the ideas are not assumed in any way to be the lecturer's ones, so (1) does not apply; but if text from an non-cited book is copied verbatim, then (2) applies.

Now, most academics I know do use from time to time other's material without proper referencing, and this seems *in practice* to be accepted (as shown by several other answers). I strongly oppose this habit, especially when the same lecturer blame student for copy-pasting Wikipedia in their homework: even if the situation is somewhat different, the message gets a bit confusing.

That does not mean that lecturers can't use other's production; they just have either to get inspiration from them instead of copy-pasting, or to give credit. This applies notably, but not exclusively, to the use of images.

Comment: Right as far as e.g. lecture notes go (those should be held to similar standards than formal publications). For scribbling on the blackboard, homework, or exam questions, this would be ludicrous.

Comment: If you use other's exercises, why not cite them? I sometimes do use exam questions that I found (e.g. in national competitions to enter French Engineering schools), but then I give a citation in footnote. What does it cost?

Comment: @Benoit: What does it cost? If you cite the exercises you're using, and the solutions are online, you are giving the students an opportunity to cheat. (For the same reason, if you take somebody else's exercises, you should reword them slightly — not to avoid plagiarism, but so they can't be found by Googling.)