# Plagiarizing Professor

Tags: ethics, professorship, plagiarism, presentation

I have a professor that pulls slides from the internet to fill his lectures. He does occasionally attribute the slides to the original author (in class, not on the slide itself) but the majority of the time his slides are either scans from a book with zero attribution or slides that can easily be found on Google with either a text or image search, again, with no attribution. His latest homework assignment is copied directly from another college's [online course documents](http://www.ece.ucsb.edu/%7Estrukov/ece154aFall2012/pp.pdf).

He is not a good educator in any sense of the word and seems to be teaching just to fulfill a teaching requirement. He comes to class, reads from his notes for 2 hours and leaves. If anyone has a question in class, he repeats what he just said and tells the person to read the book. While I obviously can't say for sure that he does not have permission from the content creators to use their lecture material without attribution, his in-class behavior lead me (and others I've spoken to in the class) to believe that is not the case.

Is this the kind of thing that should be brought to an administrators attention or should I just keep my head low and deal with another bad professor?

Comment: Also see [Citing sources of problems in assignments](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1744/citing-sources-of-problems-in-assignments) and [Plagiarism of Lecture Slides](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/56551/plagiarism-of-lecture-slides)

Comment: Mixed up in the question about plagiarizing teaching materials (which has already been covered here) is a question on whether to notify administration about a teacher who doesn't seem to put much effort into teaching, in general. That is a new one for this site, as far as I know. Perhaps you can [edit] your post to focus on that part of the situation, and I can reopen?