# What to do if my professor is plagarizing

Tags: professorship, plagiarism

I was in the middle of doing my homework for a class (its a worksheet for a word document) and I noticed that the author of the word document is not my professor.

I looked it up, and it turns out that the person who wrote the document teaches a related class at a different university.

I checked the rest of the document, and nowhere (other than the word metadata) says that it comes from this other person.

Should I do anything with this information, and if so, what?

Comment: Also see [Is it acceptable for paid online course to use quizzes and materials from elsewhere on the internet?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/66301/is-it-acceptable-for-paid-online-course-to-use-quizzes-and-materials-from-elsewh)

Comment: Also see [How widespread is sharing of slides/assignments among educators?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/65470/how-widespread-is-sharing-of-slides-assignments-among-educators)

Comment: Also see [Citing sources of problems in assignments](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1744/citing-sources-of-problems-in-assignments) and [Plagiarism of Lecture Slides](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/56551/plagiarism-of-lecture-slides)